# Is it possible for distinct geodesics to be equivalent over a finite segment?

Tags: manifolds, geodesic, general-relativity, analytic-continuation

Is it possible for two geodesics $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ to be identical within a finite interval without being identical outside the interval? IOW: $\gamma_1(t) = \gamma_2(t)$ for $t \in (A,B)$ but $\gamma_1(t) \neq \gamma_2(t)$ for some $t \notin (A,B)$.

At first glance, I would think that uniqueness (the Cauchy Lipschitz theorem) would say the answer is no, because if $\gamma_1(t) = \gamma_2(t)$ at even a single point $t = t_0$ then they are equal everywhere.

However, the paper [1] below, by the well known physicist Kip Thorne, would seem to indicate this is not always true. This paper considers the general relativistic motion of an object along a timelike geodesic $\gamma$ in a spacetime that admits closed timelike curves, and came to the surprising conclusion that there are instances where there are *multiple* solutions to the general relativistic equations of motion. Specifically, if I read the paper correctly, two (or more) solutions $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ can be equivalent up to time $t_0$ but diverge for $t > t_0$. This property is known as "multiplicity."

I am thinking that the uniqueness theorem assumes a simply connected topology that does not allow closed timelike curves, and the answer to my question requires a sophisticated understanding of topology that I do not yet possess. Perhaps $\gamma_1$ is embedded in 4-manifold $M_1$, and $\gamma_2$ is embedded in a distinct 4-manifold $M_2$, where: $M_1$ and $M_2$ are each embedded within some higher dimensional manifold; the intersection of $M_1$ and $M_2$ is a (finite? bounded?) 4-dimensional region $M_3$; $M_1$ and $M_2$ have distinct global topologies; the segment where $\gamma_1(t) = \gamma_2(t)$ is inside $M_3$, and they are unequal once they exit $M_3$. That's as far as I've gotten.

My background: I know a little about differential equations and analytic continuation but it's been a while since I've really used them. If the answer to my question is "yes, under certain conditions" then I am interested in exploring those conditions in detail, but I still have quite a lot to learn about the relevant mathematics - manifolds, tensors, topology, etc. I would appreciate any suggestions you may have on specific mathematical tools or subfields I should study. I apologize in advance if I have butchered any terminology ;) .

[1] Billiard balls in wormhole spacetimes with closed timelike curves: Classical theory. Fernando Echeverria, Gunnar Klinkhammer, and Kip S. Thorne. Phys. Rev. D 44, 1077. Published 15 August 1991. http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.44.1077

Comment: Wormholes are a topological feature, not relating well to the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, which assume what could be described as the nonexistence of multiply connect spacial slices, to use a general relativity oriented wording... To my best knowledge, from the differential equations point of view the answer to the question in the title is "no" (that is, I am not aware of any Picard-Lindelöf theorem for a nontrivial homotopy).

Comment: in a finite dimensional riemannian manifold, the answer is no. a geodesic is defined from a starting point $p$ and a direction $v \in T_p \mathcal{M}$ by $\gamma(0) = p, \dot{\gamma}(0) = v$, $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} \dot{\gamma} = 0$ with $\nabla$ being the [metric connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection). up to a re-parametrization, it  has only one solution for $\gamma(t)$ because of the diffeomorphisms to $\mathbb{R}^n$ where it is a simple  differential equation. so maybe if your manifold is not smooth everywhere you can have weird behaviors ?

Comment: Sounds like the answer is "no" under basic conditions but "maybe" under more exotic conditions. If the answer turns out to be "yes" under certain exotic conditions, then I am interested in defining what those conditions are and going from there. I would be especially interested if the answer could be yes without resorting to discontinuities of any sort, i.e. if manifold and metric were everywhere analytic. I'm still thinking the answer may be yes with certain exotic topologies. (By "thinking" I really mean "hoping"  because I would find it fascinating  :) )